# Dynamic Label Title for NSTouchBar on Swift

Tags: swift, macos, nstouchbar

I am new to swift and been learning how to do it on my own through tutorials. I was able to make the title of a button change when clicked on. I wanted to dynamically change the title of a label. It doesn't necessarily have to be clicked on like a button. **This is a label for the NStouchbar.**

The code below is how I managed to change the button label. I noticed that labels do not have the .title action so I am not sure how I would go about changing that.

```
@IBAction func buttonOneTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Button One Tapped")
    buttonOne.title = "1 BTC = $" + dollar
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the label of a button and edit it do it like this:

```
button.titleLabel?.text
```

And just as a suggestion, instead of using the + sign to concatenate a string and a float or double I would do it like this:

```
"1 BTC = $\(dollar)"
```

I forgot the name of this method :| but it's the more swifty way. :]

Comment: It's called 'string interpolation'.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, I will concatenate the string that way.